# Problem loading javascript in web C# browsercontrol

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer

i want to load a javascript in my C# web browser control. but VS does not let me do that...dis

it says something like this"to help protecting your security your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content
that could access your computer "

i have enabled the   active scripting and all the other features required to display javascripts..but
still this error keeps coming

my sample code is as follows

webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
 webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Kalpa\Desktop\MReview\Test.html");

javascript-

alert("Hello");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line

!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -- between angle brackets

in the Test.html.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx